# Referencing a .NET standard dll in both .NET core and .NET 4.6.1, System.Data.SqlClient throws PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: .net, reference, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm having issues trying use a .NET standard 2.0 library in both my .NET core 2.1 project and .NET 4.6.1 project.

I basically have 3 projects, 1 .NET standard library (targeting .NET standard 2.0) which is a provider to the other projects. This .NET standard project uses System.Data.SqlClient (4.4.0), to open a connection to the database, execute a query.

I've referenced this .NET standard DLL in my .NET core project (2.1) and everything seems to work fine, i've used SQL profiler to track whether or not the connection is opened and the query is executed.

Now when i reference this same .NET standard library in my .NET 4.6.1 project, and try to open a connection, i'm getting a System.PlatformNotSupportedException (being thrown by System.Data.SqlClient).

Would this be the correct way to use the .NET standard libraries (or did i miss something)?

Comment: Can you share more information about what the exception is (which API is throwing that exception)?

Comment: Something weird I found with .NET Standard library using `System.Data.SqlClient` in .NET 4.6.1 app was I specifically needed to add the [`System.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.5.0) NuGet package to my .NET app. Not sure if that's a bad set up on my end (possible) or something else.

Comment: Well this was one of the things i tried as well, which makes things work (eventually). But this kind of defeats the purpose. Especially since it's throwing runtime exceptions. @AlexGhiondea-MSFT as stated in my original post, the System.Data.SqlClient is throwing this exception on SqlConnection.Open() (i'll edit my post to make this more clear..)

Comment: I see -- I will try and reproduce this issue in an application and see what I can find out.